# Политика безопасности

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

Здравствуйте, проблема такая.
Создаю фрейм

```
<iframe src="http://prolegkie-info.eversmi.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

В консоли пишет вот такую ошибку.

> Refused to display 'http://prolegkie-info.eversmi.com/544?page=full'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://webvisor.com".

В чём может быть проблема? Если в iframe подставить другой src прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот сайт (который в параметре `src`) запрещает демонстрировать свои страницы в фреймах всем, чьи страницы не на `http://webvisor.com`. Браузер прямо пишет, что запрет вызван настройками Content Security Policy, а именно опцией `frame-ancestors`.

Фишка относится к **[Content Security Policy Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors)**.

Ранее существовал аналогичный механизм в виде `X-Frame-Options`, но его вариация с "белым списком доменов" (`ALLOW`) широко так и не распространилась. А вот `DENY` и `SAMEORIGIN` поддерживаются куда чаще. Сейчас его используют больше из соображений совместимости.

А пришедший ему на замену **CSP L2** явно требует игнорировать `X-Frame-Options`, если задан CSP с `frame-ancestors`. Так что `X-Frame-Options` ни при чём. **В вашем браузере.** Браузер постарше мог бы не понять заголовок CSP, но обратить внимание на полный запрет любого* встраивания через `X-Frame-Options`. В результате, правда, поведение несколько отличается: такой браузер заблокировал бы загрузку и в фрейме на `webvisor.com`.

Это выбор владельцев сайта в фрейме, который доносится через HTTP-заголовок ответа их сайта. Со своей стороны вы ничего не можете с ним сделать.

---

* Это если `DENY`. Если `SAMEORIGIN`, то действует запрет на встраивание везде, кроме страниц этого же самого сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Данный сайт использует [заголовок Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

В котором используется директива [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)

Эта директива определяет допустимых родителей, которые могут встроить данный сайт используя  `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>` или `<applet>`.

В данном случае использовано значение: `frame-ancestors http://webvisor.com;`

Что разрешает встраивать сайт только *webvisor.com*